# Dynamic JAXB/MOXy Marshalling throws MOXy BV: Facets generation could not be configured

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am trying to follow the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/jpatoxml006.htm) and implement the `Dynamic JAXB/Moxy marshalling`. But it's not working as desired and throws the following error:

```
[EL Warning]: moxy: 2021-05-28 10:54:09.432--MOXy BV: Facets generation could not be configured. EclipseLink's JavaModelInputImpl was not detected, instead JavaModelInput is of class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.xjc.XJCJavaModelInputImpl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My `XSD` is in the `resources` folder and I am using the `XSD` from the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/jpatoxml006.htm#:%7E:text=Example%2015-27%20Sample%20XML%20Schema%20Document). After reading I am trying to create the `POJO` for it on the go and using the marshaling method to create the XML. Following is the code for it:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        final ClassLoader classLoader = Demo.class.getClassLoader();
        final InputStream xsd = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("customer.xsd");
        //final InputStream xml = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("customer.xml");

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put("eclipselink.beanvalidation.facets", true);

        System.setProperty("com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.noCorrectnessCheck", "true");
        final DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsd, null, classLoader, properties);
        DynamicEntity customer = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("org.JaxBDynamic.Customer");
        DynamicEntity address = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("org.JaxBDynamic.Address");
        customer.set("name", "Jane Doe");
        address.set("street", "1 Any Street").set("city", "Any Town");
        customer.set("address", address);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }
}
```

I have following `dependency` in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run I get following error:

```
[EL Warning]: moxy: 2021-05-28 10:54:09.432--MOXy BV: Facets generation could not be configured. EclipseLink's JavaModelInputImpl was not detected, instead JavaModelInput is of class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.xjc.XJCJavaModelInputImpl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.preProcessXmlAccessorType(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.preBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClassesAndProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext$SchemaContextInput.createContextState(DynamicJAXBContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext.<init>(DynamicJAXBContext.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(DynamicJAXBContextFactory.java:281)
    at com.JaxBDynamic.Demo.main(Demo.java:25)
```

I am not sure what's wrong as I am following the steps as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/jpatoxml006.htm). I could not find anything related to this issue so posting here to get some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you are trying to implement JAXB following documentation, but the documentation you linked is for EclipseLink version 2.5 and you are running into problems with a feature that was added in EL v2.6. The current stable release is 3.0.0, which you are running, based on your `pom.xml`.

Check out the newer documentation for EL. And since the link for the documentation for the feature you are running into problems with is not present on the homepage, you can find it here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/BVinJAXB and presentation of the concepts [here](https://bugzillaattachments.eclipsecontent.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=252463).

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

The message

```
"[EL Warning]: moxy: 2022-01-06 14:59:32.0--MOXy BV: Facets generation could not be configured. EclipseLink's JavaModelInputImpl was not detected, instead..."
```

is not responsible for the NullPointerException, Hence, it is not an issue. Apart from it use matching versions of Eclipselink moxy and jasb-xjc:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If there, remove file jaxb.properties as it is not needed in case of dynamic jaxb context.